Should skin dissolve completely in bone/skin broth?
I just made my first attempt at bone-and-skin broth in my new Instant Pot pressure cooker. I'm more interested in the broth as a source of amino acids from the collagenous material than as a source of minerals from the bones. I used the skin, bones and fat from half a free-range pig's head. I cooked somewhere around 2kg of solids in about 2L of water for about 2h on high pressure (guided by the chart in this article). I didn't add vinegar, partly because I've read it can cause toxic nickel to leach from the steel, partly because I wanted to see how the broth came out with heat and pressure only. I strained the solids from the liquid and it is currently chilling in my fridge, waiting to be skimmed and tasted tomorrow.
What I'd like to know is this: after cooking, the pieces of skin and connective tissue were very soft but not dissolved; does that mean that much of the collagen has not gone into the broth? Should I use a blender to incorporate the collagenous material into the liquid? Or keep cooking until it dissolves? Or does enough get extracted without them dissolving?

Update
The broth forms a firmish gelatin at fridge temperature, so evidently quite a lot of amino acids were incorporated; but I still wonder if more could/should be.

It would probably completely dissolve eventually (after no more than a few weeks of boiling), but it's not expected with normal broth-boiling durations. Whether you should blend all or some of the remaining skin is up to you, and the texture you're looking for. I've done just that for ramen broth and for souse but it results in an extremely gelatinous broth which may not be what you want.

If blending the remaining skin makes the broth noticeably more gelatinous then I think that means the answer to my question is 'Yes, those pieces of skin retain significant amounts of collagen.'. Thanks.
